# Getting “rospack package not found error” in ROS

Tags: ros

I created a package in catkin workspace and put a publisher.py node inside the src directory of package which worked fine. Then i added another node subscriber.py node and used catkin_make to build. Now when I try to run any of the nodes or find package i am getting above error. Am I missing any step ?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much .
Writing source devel/setup.bash worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going wrong from just from you describing the error (might be better to paste the message directly..Sounds like a problem with your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable. I'm assuming you're following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29))? I remember having had this problem before, so some possible things to try:

- You may need to just type in `source devel/setup.bash` into your terminal.
- Make sure your bash.rc file is properly set. Refer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053334/ros-package-not-found-after-catkin-make) (If I remember correctly, if you don't want to type in `source devel/setup.bash` every time you open up a new terminal you can edit the bash.rc file.)
- Check that your CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is right.

Also, try entering `rospack find [package_name]` into the terminal to find the path to the package.